# How to remove records in php array where there are same values in one column

Tags: php, arrays

I have a below 2D array. I want to remove duplicate records from array since they have the same 'EmployeeId' as 12345. These records can have different values for other columns. I tried array_unique(). However, it needs all the values to be the same.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeId] => 12345
            [FirstName] => John
            [LastName] => Smith
            [Age] => 30
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeId] => 12345
            [FirstName] => Joe
            [LastName] => Marsh
            [Age] => 45
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeId] => 45678
            [FirstName] => Ellie
            [LastName] => Smith
            [Age] => 78
        )
)
```

Output should be

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [EmployeeId] => 45678
            [FirstName] => Ellie
            [LastName] => Smith
            [Age] => 78
        )
)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Thefourthbird I think all the solutions there require the entire sub-array to be the same, not a single property.

Comment: Turn your array into an associative array that uses the employee ID as the key. Since keys must be unique, this will remove all the duplicates.

Comment: @Barmar Good point, I will remove the comment.